# Javascript, php and html compiler

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a web application which is mostly programmed in javascript but there is also PHP which is driving MYSQL database. Everything clothed in HTML of course.

I would like to compile this to exe file to make it work standalone. 
Is there any way to do that ?

Comment: Doesn't the wamp server fit your needs? http://www.wampserver.com/en/

Comment: How much of it do you want packaged into a client-side binary? Will the MySQL database still live remotely, or will that also be run locally on the client's machine? This is a bit of an odd way to go about making a desktop application, if not unheard of, so there will probably be some unforeseen road bumps.

Comment: If the server-side part can remain server-side, try node-webkit: https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit

Answer (score 0):

Try ZZEE PHPExe.
From: http://www.zzee.com/phpexe/html-exe.php, "ZZEE PHPExe compiles HTML, PHP, Javascript, Flash and other web files into standard Windows GUI exes."

Alternatively, you could try ExeOutput for PHP. From: http://www.exeoutput.com/, "Applications made with ExeOutput for PHP run PHP scripts, PHP applications, and PHP websites natively, and do not require a web server, a web browser, or PHP distribution. They are stand-alone and work on any computer with recent Windows versions."

Answer (score -1):

1. Try [HipHop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HipHop_for_PHP).
2. I don't use Windows any longer, but take a look at [Cameyo](http://www.cameyo.com) or search the web for a simmelar solution. Install there an small webserver, PHP and Mysql and add your script.
   Negative on your solution is that this will take a LOT of space (probobly ~100MB).